# Installing RDKit in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, rdkit

I cannot figure out how to fix the following issue. Up until today I was using the following code snippet for installing RDKit in Google Colab:

```
!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
!time bash ./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!time conda install -q -y -c conda-forge rdkit

import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')
```

However, today I started to get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d24c24e2d1f9> in <module>()
----> 1 from rdkit import Chem
      2 import networkx as nx

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rdkit'
```

I've tried using the full Anaconda distribution instead of Miniconda, as well as changing the python version to 3.6 and 3.8 but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Here in the distant future (September 2021), RDKit is installable with `pip3 install rdkit-pypi` (works fine in Colabs).

Comment: Just `%pip install rdkit`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to specify python 3.7 when you install Miniconda (the current rdkit build supports python 3.7), the latest Miniconda version is py3.8:

```
!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-py37_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-py37_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh
!time bash ./Miniconda3-py37_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!time conda install -q -y -c conda-forge rdkit

import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')
```

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MAZyv3O4-TrI8c1MD4JVmwExDquaprRT?usp=sharing

Comment: This worked, thanks! Doing !time conda install -y python=3.6 worked as well

Comment: Not working any more: This worked for me: https://gist.github.com/philopon/a75a33919d9ae41dbed5bc6a39f5ede2

Answer (score 4):

I created a Python package to simplify the setup. You can find it [here](https://github.com/jaimergp/condacolab).

It will install Miniconda (or any other flavour) and patch a couple things that make Colab tricky.

Use it like this (first cell in your notebook):

```
!pip install -q condacolab
import condacolab
condacolab.install()
```

The kernel will restart and then you will be able to run `conda` or `mamba` with the `!shell` syntax:

```
!mamba install -c conda-forge rdkit
```

Check the repository for more details!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid installing Conda, you can just extract the anaconda package

```py
# version 2018 is quite easy
# download & extract
url = 'https://anaconda.org/rdkit/rdkit/2018.09.1.0/download/linux-64/rdkit-2018.09.1.0-py36h71b666b_1.tar.bz2'
!curl -L $url | tar xj lib
# move to python packages directory
!mv lib/python3.6/site-packages/rdkit /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/
x86 = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
!mv lib/*.so.* $x86/
# rdkit need libboost_python3.so.1.65.1
!ln -s $x86/libboost_python3-py36.so.1.65.1 $x86/libboost_python3.so.1.65.1
```

For the latest version, it's a bit more complicate due to libboost 1.67. So, I put it in my `kora` library.

```py
!pip install kora -q
import kora.install.rdkit
```

You'll get version `2020.09.1`

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the below pip it will work properly

```
!pip install rdkit-pypi -qqq
```